# OO style alternatives of int 2D array of ints

Tags: arrays, oop, multidimensional-array, data-structures, collections

I frequently use 2D arrays to handle various problems in Java. I know 2D array is more of a C way of doing things. I would like to get opinions on what are the object oriented alternatives to 2D array. I realise most people just go ahead and use it without looking at the alternatives that may be available in the OO style. Apart from collections (hashmap, arraylist etc) what are other alternatives and their performance advantages over 2d array.

Thank you.

Comment: You should show code using 2D arrays to see how you could refactor it to use OOP approaches...

Comment: There's "encapsulate a row/column" of course but whether that's actually useful/logical obviously depends on what you're modeling and what you're doing with it.

Answer (score 0):

For most cases two-dimensional arrays are okay.

Using objects only makes sense if your arrays represent some meaningful object.

- If you are doing mathematics look at a linear algebra library with `Matrix` classes.
- If you are doing image processing there might even be an `Image` class in the Java core packages.
- Otherwise you're probably fine with just an array.